# Работа большими числами

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста как работать с большими числами, такие как, 10^90(можно и меньше) uint64_t не помогает

Comment: OpenSSL например

Comment: Десятки дубликатов вопроса не смущают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
    mp::cpp_int num1 ("12347893489239423480238407238947892349823");
    mp::cpp_int num2 ("487658923425734580234503495059345034250349534059234");
    std::cout << num1 * num2 << std::endl;
}
```

Ссылка на мануал и библиотеку: [тут](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: страница не доступна

Comment: Как? Перепроверьте.

Comment: Сайт www.boost.org не отправил данных.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: У меня все работает...

Comment: По крайней мере есть [тут](http://evilcoderr.blogspot.ru/2013/01/boost-c-vs-2010.html).

Comment: Это обязательно делать:Теперь открываем Пуск->Все Программы->Microsoft Visual Studio->Visual Studio Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)?

Comment: Это я к примеру. Какая у Вас IDE?

Comment: Если Visual Studio, то да, обязательно)

Comment: visual studio 2015. Просто нет этой папки и этого приожения

Comment: Ну вот) Только версия командной строки тогда может отличаться.

Comment: Да? Хм... Даже не знаю... Может другие есть? С "Visual Studio" в названии?

Comment: через поиск искал, не нашел

Comment: Значит это кряк?

Comment: не понял, что подразумевате под кряком?

Comment: Погодите... А может у Вас стоит Visual Studio CODE?

Comment: нет, не стоит )

Comment: Ну уж не знаю. Попробуйте для начала тип long long...

Comment: мало, было бы так просто)